# Metasploit: Starting paylolad handler... not showing

Tags: exploit, android, metasploit

I want to hack into my own android device (Wiko Lenny 3 with Android 6.0).

But everytime I press enter after I typed "exploit", it states `Exploit running as background job 0` and the message `Starting payload handler...` doesn't show.

When I open the app on my phone, nothing happens, the app doesn't even open in any way and no session gets opened in terminal.

Please help!

[image: screenshot of metasploit running]

Comment: When you say "open the app" on my phone, i assume you mean your meterpreter payload? Can you how you generated the payload?

Comment: Yes I open the apk I can hack into my android with but nothing appears

Comment: Could be a lot of factors. Are the phone and the Kali with Metasploit on same network and is the phone able to connect to Kali machine? Or maybe your apk is not well constructed. Put the msfvenom command you used to create it or tell us how did you created it.

Comment: as OscarAkaElvis mentioned . please check whether your phone and laptop share a same network or not .  IMO  the problem is in creating your apk . so double check it.

Comment: The problem that you describe is not about the handler or Kali, but about the APK and possibly networking. You do not describe the configuration of the payload or anything about the networking. Please edit your question to include these things. And please do not post images of text but copy/paste and use the code formatting tool.